How to filter Cloudflare GraphQL API query for specific page statistics?
I'm using the Cloudflare GraphQL API to fetch traffic statistics by zone. So far, I've been able to retrieve general data using queries like this:
$query = [
    "query" => "{
        viewer {
            zones(filter: {zoneTag: \"$zone_id\"}) {
                httpRequests1dGroups(limit: 30, filter: {date_gt: \"$startDate\", date_lt: \"$endDate\"}) {
                    sum {
                        requests,
                        pageViews
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }"
];

Now, I'm trying to create a filter to get statistics specific to a page on my site, for example, example.com/thispage. I couldn't find in the Cloudflare documentation how to add this filter to my GraphQL query. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this filtering using the Cloudflare GraphQL API?
I tried looking at the API Documentation: See if the Cloudflare API documentation provides examples or specific information about how to filter by pages or URLs, but I didn't find anything that worked
